# ARR Reverse Proxy on Azure Website removes WebSockets response header 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept'

Tags: iis, azure, reverse-proxy, arr

I'm trying to setup ARR inside of an Azure Website. I have a working implementation on an Azure VM, but would like to move to a Website so I don't have to actively manage the VM.

The issue I am having is specific to the SignalR WebSockets connection request and response that passes through my ARR reverse proxy.

Response on server before passing through ARR via IIS Request Tracing:

```
Upgrade: Websocket
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ARR/3.0
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: IVoaaOhRLbaSxQzHV1TRkwHbtFc=**
Connection: Upgrade
X-FE-DATA: AppId:Unknown-StatusCode
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
DWAS-Handler-Name: EXECUTE|101|0|0x0|CONFIG_SUCCESS|ApplicationRequestRoutingHandler|::1|\\100.68.100.59\volume-21-default\be0a77feeba577989612\3323291baecf417bb67a391f58af8a90\
```

Response as seen by the client:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: Websocket
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ARR/3.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Connection: Upgrade
```

As you can see, the `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` header is being stripped out of the response. This means that the client fails the connection and defaults to long-polling instead of websockets protocol.

Any idea why this header is being removed? ARR 3.0 is being used which has native websockets support, and websockets is enabled in the Azure Website configuration panel.

Comment: I also just ran into this issue, trying to run a WAMP router in Azure.

Comment: However in my case the HTTP header being stripped out is 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol:'

Comment: I reported this to Microsoft, they acknowledged the problem, but no ETA for a fix yet. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d7f6bc70-a1c6-4d6c-ac00-ead09244d29f/secwebsocketprotocol-http-header-stripped-by-arr?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Comment: Thank you for doing that, @PaulFryer

Comment: To anyone else having this issue, I've figured out a workaround by using an Azure Cloud Service instead of an Azure Website. Using a startup task i was able to get IIS configured to my liking.

Comment: yes that's a known work around (using cloud service) but in my scenario I wanted to use the websites for auto scaling and less to manage. I did however find a workaround by changing the javascript that was looking for the 'Sec-WebScoket-Protocol' header. I don't feel good about that since it's a 3rd party JS library, but it works for now.

Answer (score 1):

Did you specify the flag to preserveHostHeaders="true" in the proxy config?

```
 <proxy xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" enabled="true" preserveHostHeader="true" reverseRewriteHostInResponseHeaders="true" />
```